# F# async try ... finally do! AwaitTask

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task-parallel-library

**Problem, short:**

In an `async{...}` expression, in a `try-finally` expression, how can I use `do! ... |> Async.AwaitTask` in the `finally` block?

**Problem, long; failing snippet:**

I fail to aggregate all exceptions when awaiting a chain of nested asynchronous tasks.

My design intention is that each task eventually awaits its predecessing task, and I expect the Task-Parallel-Library uses the AggregateException to combine all exceptions observed.

Each async/task may throw an exception; the following minimal example chains/nests two asynchronous tasks, each throwing an exception:

```
async {
    let actionBefore =
        async {
            printfn "doing sth before..."
            failwith "! fail during sth before"
        }
        |> Async.StartAsTask

    printfn "doing sth now..."
    failwith "! fail during sth now"

    do! actionBefore |> Async.AwaitTask
}
|> Async.StartAsTask
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

My question is, without changing the starting and awaiting order, how do I have to add try-catch- or try-finally-blocks so that both exceptions will be reported by the final Async.AwaitTask?

I am using F# version 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in async/task, but I think the main problem here is that `do! actionBefore |> Async.AwaitTask` can never execute, so there's no way to catch its exception.

Instead, I suggest that you start each action as a separate task, and then use `Task.WhenAll` to await both of them:

```ml
async {
    let actionBefore =
        async {
            printfn "doing sth before..."
            failwith "! fail during sth before"
        }
        |> Async.StartAsTask

    let actionNow =
        async {
            printfn "doing sth now..."
            failwith "! fail during sth now"
        }
        |> Async.StartAsTask

    do! Task.WhenAll(actionBefore, actionNow)
        |> Async.AwaitTask
        |> Async.Ignore
}
|> Async.StartAsTask
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This results in an `AggregateException` that contains two inner exceptions, which is what I think you want.

Note that you don't need the outer `async` in this case, so I think the following version is simpler:

```ml
let actionBefore =
    async {
        printfn "doing sth before..."
        failwith "! fail during sth before"
    }
    |> Async.StartAsTask

let actionNow =
    async {
        printfn "doing sth now..."
        failwith "! fail during sth now"
    }
    |> Async.StartAsTask

Task.WhenAll(actionBefore, actionNow)
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore
```

Comment: This answers my question to the point, for me this is the "accepted answer" for the present F# 5. I also liked the additional details given below by [@Tomas Petricek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33518/tomas-petricek), but these would imply to write some small helper to make up for missing language/core library support -- which is not my idea of an industry language -- but I expect this will change soon with F# 6 (and future versions) anyway. (Doing "plain F#" with async-only is the right way, or going by interopability with an async-task-mix, that is ... another topic.)

Comment: Right, the main issue here is that F# provides an `async` builder, but you've chosen to use .NET tasks instead, which are a different solution to the same problem. The helper functions are only needed to bridge the two worlds. The good news, as you suggest, is that F# 6 will have [better built-in support for tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-fsharp-6/).

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer shows the key trick, which is to use `Task.WhenAll` - unlike other options, this waits for all the tasks and aggregates all exceptions. Just to add to this, I think it's confusing that you have to mix tasks and asyncs here. The plain F# way of doing this is to use `Async.StartChild`, but this fails whenever the first computation fails:

```
async {
  let! t1 = Async.StartChild <| async {
    printfn "doing sth before..."
    failwith "! fail during sth before" }
  let! t2 = Async.StartChild <| async {
    printfn "doing sth now..."
    failwith "! fail during sth now" }
  let! r1 = t1
  let! r2 = t2
  return r1, r2 }
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

There is no `Async.WhenAll`, but you can define that using `Task.WhenAll`. Here is a simpler version with just two arguments:

```
module Async = 
  let WhenBoth(a1, a2) = async {
    let r1 = a1 |> Async.StartAsTask
    let r2 = a2 |> Async.StartAsTask
    let! _ = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(r1, r2) |> Async.AwaitTask
    return r1.Result, r2.Result }
```

That way, you can write what you originally wanted in a fairly clean way, just using `async`:

```
async {
  let! t1 = Async.StartChild <| async {
    printfn "doing sth before..."
    failwith "! fail during sth before" }
  let! t2 = Async.StartChild <| async {
    printfn "doing sth now..."
    failwith "! fail during sth now" }
  return! Async.WhenBoth(t1, t2) }
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Thanks! The first step alone, translating the problem into "plain F#" (without resorting to interoperability, without using Task/TPL directly) is already extremely instructive! My concern is, that - working in software industry, not sw research - I shy away from using any little helpers that make up for missing support from the language or its core library; without such standardized functionality, programmers start to write down (or copy down) their own versions, which then becomes hell to maintain.